# How to set a Directory path in WIX using CustomAction?

Tags: c#, wix, custom-action

I have a directory structure like this in WIX

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir" >
  <Directory Id="XXXFOLDER" Name="XXX">
    <Directory Id="YYYFOLDER" Name="YYY">
      <Directory Id="MAINFOLDER" Name="MAIN">
```

Now this MAINFOLDER Directory Resolves to D:\XXX\YYY\MAIN\

I get a path for the MAINFOLDER from a service which resolves to E:\XXX\YYY\MAIN
I have also assigned a customAction in a cs file
Below is the code

## [CustomAction]

```
    public static ActionResult GetNewDataPath(Session session)
    {
        
        sNewDataDir = xxxservice.GetPath();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(sNewDataDir.ToString()))
        {
            sNewDataDir+= "\\MAIN\\";
        }
        
        session["MAINFOLDER"] = sNewDataDir;
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

My Custom Actions are as below :

```
<CustomAction Id="GETDATAPATH" BinaryKey="InstallerCA"      
  DllEntry="GetNewDataPath" Execute="immediate"/>
```

This is the Install Sequence:

```
<Custom Action="GETDATAPATH" Before="CostFinalize" />
```

The sNewDataDir contains this value = "E:\XXX\YYY\MAIN" and I assign to session["MAINFOLDER"]. It gets assigned. But It does not get reflected on WIX side because my files are still being copied to D:\XXX\YYY\Main inspite of assigning it to E:\XXX\YYY\Main . How do we change the direcory path of session["MAINFOLDER"] using CustomAction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's usually a matter of sequence. The values of the properties are assigned to the Directory paths during the CostFinalize action [per MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367852(v=vs.85).aspx). You're custom action above must be sequenced sometime before CostFinalize runs in the execute sequence.

It can also be a matter of privilege: MAINFOLDER may be a restricted public property and isn't making it to the execute sequence (doesn't apply if your custom action ran in the execute sequence). Read about [Restricted Public Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371243(v=vs.85).aspx) to see if that might be your issue.

And it can also be your computer's [anti-virus](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robmen/2004/05/20/vbscript-and-jscript-msi-customactions-suck/) or [some](http://blogs.msdn.com/heaths/archive/2007/05/31/windows-installer-errors-2738-and-2739-with-script-custom-actions.aspx) other [issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/06/07/3151752.aspx) with the script engines.

To have a good idea (or at least find someone else who can figure out what the issue really is) you will need to generate a good log of your failed attempt. Most of the time [voicewarmup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370536(v=vs.85).aspx) (or /l*v) is the best value to use (tends to give you most but not all of what you want, along with way too much of what you don't) and is the value most installation development experts use when generating the logs they use and share. It does slow down your installs a fair bit, however.

Comment: @ B. Murri - I tried applying CostInitialize in the Before Attribute but its not working. I have edited the above code to add the CustomAction. CAn you just check if that is alright?

Comment: Looks correct. What does your logging show around that action being called?

Comment: Finally rectified the issue. I was just changing the parent folder path that is MAINFOLDER path and not the folders inside MAINFOLDER due to which the path was not updated. Now I manually updated all the paths of the folder through a custom action and it works fine. Thanks